# Promise not being resolved when run inside Jasmine unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocking, jasmine

Facing a strange issue when testing a method that returns a promise in Jasmine unit tests. I have the following class:

```
import http = require('http');
import https = require('https');
import fs = require('fs');

export default class ImageDownloader {
    constructor(protected downloadPath:string) {}

    async download(url: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            let file = fs.createWriteStream(this.downloadPath, { autoClose: true });
            let schema:any = url.startsWith('https') ? https : http;

            schema.get(url, (response:fs.ReadStream) => {
                response.pipe(file).on('finish', () => resolve(this.downloadPath));
            }).on('error', (error) => reject(error));
        });
    }
}
```

It downloads an image to the download path given in the constructor, and then resolves the promise with that download path once the file has been written to disk.

I've written a Jasmine unit test:

```
import fs = require('fs');
import http = require('http');
import ImageDownloader from '../../src/Image/ImageDownloader';

describe('Image Downloader', () => {
    describe('download()', () => {
        it('returns the path to the downloaded image', done => {
            spyOn(http, 'get').and.callFake((url, cb) => {
                cb(fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/../assets/elephpant.png'));
            });

            let imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader('/tmp/image');

            imageDownloader.download('http://foo.bar/bazz.jpg').then((path) => {
                expect(path).toEqual('/tmp/image');
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In this test, I mock the Node `http` module in order to return my own faked "HTTP response". Remember that Node's `IncomingMessage` class (what would normally be returned as the response from `http.get()`) implements the readable stream interface, so I'm just returning my own readable stream with `fs.createReadStream()`.

When running this test, it just times out because the promise is never getting resolved:

```
F
Failures: 
1) Image Downloader download() returns the path to the downloaded image
1.1) Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

However, the weird part is that if I change the part of the `download()` method that resolves the promise to this:

```
response.pipe(file).on('finish', () => console.log('the promise would normally be resolved here'));
```

I see this output:

```
the promise would normally be resolved here
F
Failures: 
1) Image Downloader download() returns the path to the downloaded image
1.1) Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

So we're obviously getting to the part when the promise is called. It's like I'm calling `resolve()` but the promise is not resolving for some reason.